# Find the maximal ideals of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Find the maximal ideals of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$.

I don't know where to start on this one.

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Notice that there is ring epimorphism $\phi :\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z_{36}$. Find all maximal ideals in $\mathbb Z$ and use this morphism to find ideals in $\mathbb Z_{36}$.

Comment: I get that only $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ are maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct plan of attack to get you started, since I guess the point of the problem is for you to get an understanding of what ideals are rather than use theorems.

What are the subgroups of $(Z_{36}, +)$?  Every ideal must be a subgroup of the additive group.
Which of these subgroups are also ideals (that is, they satisfy that if $a\in I$ and $b \in Z_{36}$ then $ab \in I$)?
Order the ideals you get (except the whole ring) by containment.  Which of them are not contained in any other (i.e., they are maximal)?

Comment: you want that A to be a Z. You got it .. nvm.

Comment: Haha, you caught it in the ~30 seconds before I fixed it.

Comment: Exactly !! ....

Comment: Another approach is to consider which ideals give fields when you take a quotient. This might be easier than ordering the ideals by containment, and since we know what the finite fields look like, we can immediately eliminate some of the ideals...